# Similar tool to Pixel Window, pixel measurement tool

Tags: pixel, measurement

I need a small application to measure pixels on screen. 
So far I've been using [Pixel Window](http://www.pixelwindowapp.com/) and I like it a lot, its small, its very simple to use and overall its a very handy app.

But I'm looking for something simmilar that has a grid on it, something that I can customize, like an 5x5px grid or 10x10px etc, or with the option to add a 960 over it, something like what GridFox does in Firefox but in the same app as the pixel measurement tool.

What do you use to measure pixels on screen(on websites for example, or in different UI of apps etc)

Comment: Mac? Windows? ..

Comment: windows, if there is an AIR app that you know of that would be perfect, if not any kind of app, also let me know about the mac one if you know one for mac, but I need one for windows

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any Windows suggestions, but [Xscope](http://xscopeapp.com) is an excellent screen measurement tool for Mac.